# JQuery / Javascript Smart Guides with css zoom

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have been looking recently at adding 'smart guides' to one of my JQuery Draggable projects. The project uses a variable zoom level, for which I have made compensation in my code. However I cannot make this code and my smart guide code work together.

When I use zoom:1 it works, but with zoom:0.7, for example, the divs start to bounce around when dragged and the guides sometimes refuse to show.

Any help would be appreciated!

*All of the code originated from Stack Overflow*

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/adminb/zZ22h/

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="other-objects" style="left:0px;top:300px;background:#a00;"></div>
    <div class="other-objects"></div>
    <div class="other-objects" style="left:400px;top:20px;"></div>
    <div class="objectx"></div>
    <div class="objecty"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    zoom:0.8;
}
.other-objects {
    background:#aaa;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    left:140px;
    top:50px;
}
.objectx {
    display:none;
    //background:#fff;
    width:0px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:10px;
    border-left: 1px solid yellow;
}
.objecty {
    display:none;
    //background:#fff;
    width:100%;
    height:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

JQuery / Javascript

```
$.ui.plugin.add("draggable", "smartguides", {
    start: function (event, ui) {
        var i = $(this).data("draggable"),
            o = i.options;
        i.elements = [];
        $(o.smartguides.constructor != String ? (o.smartguides.items || ':data(draggable)') : o.smartguides).each(function () {
            var $t = $(this);
            var $o = $t.offset();
            if (this != i.element[0]) i.elements.push({
                item: this,
                width: $t.outerWidth(),
                height: $t.outerHeight(),
                top: $o.top,
                left: $o.left
            });
        });
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(".objectx").css({
            "display": "none"
        });
        $(".objecty").css({
            "display": "none"
        });
    },
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        ui.position.top = Math.round(ui.position.top / zoom); //Compensate for zoom
        ui.position.left = Math.round(ui.position.left / zoom); //Compensate for zoom
        var inst = $(this).data("draggable"),
            o = inst.options;
        var d = o.tolerance;
        $(".objectx").css({
            "display": "none"
        });
        $(".objecty").css({
            "display": "none"
        });
        var x1 = ui.offset.left,
            x2 = x1 + inst.helperProportions.width,
            y1 = ui.offset.top,
            y2 = y1 + inst.helperProportions.height,
            xc = (x1 + x2) / 2,
            yc = (y1 + y2) / 2;
        for (var i = inst.elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var l = inst.elements[i].left,
                r = l + inst.elements[i].width,
                t = inst.elements[i].top,
                b = t + inst.elements[i].height,
                hc = (l + r) / 2,
                vc = (t + b) / 2;
            var ls = Math.abs(l - x2) <= d;
            var rs = Math.abs(r - x1) <= d;
            var ts = Math.abs(t - y2) <= d;
            var bs = Math.abs(b - y1) <= d;
            var hs = Math.abs(hc - xc) <= d;
            var vs = Math.abs(vc - yc) <= d;
            if (ls) {
                ui.position.left = inst._convertPositionTo("relative", {
                    top: 0,
                    left: l - inst.helperProportions.width
                }).left - inst.margins.left;
                $(".objectx").css({
                    "left": l - d - 4,
                        "display": "block"
                });
            }
            if (rs) {
                ui.position.left = inst._convertPositionTo("relative", {
                    top: 0,
                    left: r
                }).left - inst.margins.left;
                $(".objectx").css({
                    "left": r - d - 4,
                        "display": "block"
                });
            }

            if (ts) {
                ui.position.top = inst._convertPositionTo("relative", {
                    top: t - inst.helperProportions.height,
                    left: 0
                }).top - inst.margins.top;
                $(".objecty").css({
                    "top": t - d - 4,
                        "display": "block"
                });
            }
            if (bs) {
                ui.position.top = inst._convertPositionTo("relative", {
                    top: b,
                    left: 0
                }).top - inst.margins.top;
                $(".objecty").css({
                    "top": b - d - 4,
                        "display": "block"
                });
            }
            if (hs) {
                ui.position.left = inst._convertPositionTo("relative", {
                    top: 0,
                    left: hc - inst.helperProportions.width / 2
                }).left - inst.margins.left;
                $(".objectx").css({
                    "left": hc - d - 4,
                        "display": "block"
                });
            }
            if (vs) {
                ui.position.top = inst._convertPositionTo("relative", {
                    top: vc - inst.helperProportions.height / 2,
                    left: 0
                }).top - inst.margins.top;
                $(".objecty").css({
                    "top": vc - d - 4,
                        "display": "block"
                });
            }
        };
    }
});
$('.other-objects').draggable({
    containment: 'parent',
    smartguides: ".other-objects",
    tolerance: 5
});
var zoom = $('#parent').css('zoom');
```

Answer (score 0):

The css property zoom is not standard and seems to have all sort of problems, depends on the browser and does not work on firefox or opera.

Why simply not use the css3 transform scale method instead?
(don't forget to remove zoom and adjust the #parent margin after the scale)

```
-ms-transform: scale(0.7,0.7); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(0.7,0.7); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: scale(0.7,0.7);
```

Comment: This makes no difference to the 'jumping div' problem, although I agree that it is better than just the zoom property.

Comment: I've tested on your fiddle, and the div no longer jumps and moves smoothly. Tested on Chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: I also use chrome, version 34.0.1847.131, but still seem to get the problem with my updated fiddle :(   Could you post an updated fiddle link please?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/nB5He/
The drag motion seems to be smooth but does not track the mouse movements correctly on the borders.